# Overlay says jQuery is not defined when reloading after validation error

Tags: plone

I have a form view with a JavaScript that hides some of its fields on load. If a validation error occurs when I submit it, the form is reloaded with the error message as it should be. After reloadig it, the script is executed and the fields are hidden too.

But when I use the form as an overlay, it fails. I open the overlay, the script is executed and the fields are hidden. I post the form, a validation error occurs, and the form is reloaded with the error message, but this time the script that hides the fields is not executed.

Firebug says four times that jQuery is not defined. But the error is not in my code, it's in the javascript generated by plone. The form has four date fields and they generate the inline code that produce the errors:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (jQuery().dateinput) { ... }
</script>
```

What can I do to get my script executed after the form is reloaded under those circumstances?

I'm using Plone 4.1.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's jQuery controlling that overlay, and if it's a real overlay and not an iframe, it's happening within the pre-existing page environment, which includes jQuery.
So, this is a very odd occurrence, and you're going to need to look for an odd explanation. Any chance you've got some component trying to redefine jQuery or load a new version?

Comment: The overlay is produced by plone.app.jquerytools, so it is controlled by jQuery, and it isn't an iframe. And jQuery is defined in the main page, it is accesible in the console. There's a different page that uses its own jQuery version inside an iframe, but that's an unrelated page, so I'm pretty sure there's not a jQuery version conflict. Could it be an work-around, a way to invoke the script after the second overlay is loaded?

Comment: "jQuery is not defined error" was related to jQuery versions - some other poor guy had it last week in IRC

Comment: So, jdinuncio, do you have other JavaScript-related add-ons installed? Let's work the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have a script to embed openERP that includes jQuery 1.6. But, it caused jQuery version conflicts (of course :), so I isolated everything related to it in an iframe. Besides, in my test page that piece of code isn't called. How could I identify the source of the jQuery version conflict? If I type in the console jQuery.fn.jquery I get "1.4.4" as it should be. There's one curious thing. The console reports that the error are because jQUery is not defined in jQuery().dateInput inside @@context-new-ticket, but it reports a wrong number line in each four cases.

Comment: I'd say it's time to start instrumenting the problem. Add some alert or console log code to things like the resource that loads jq 1.6. Make sure it's only loading when you think it is.

Comment: I added the console.log line in the file that includes jQuery 1.6. It is not loaded. My project has only eight javascript files and only that one has its own jQuery version.